# Select only one record from many duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello im using the below query to select some elements from the db.

```
SELECT *,c.slug AS pslug,d.slug AS catslug 
FROM uhhu_virtuemart_products as a 
LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_products_el_gr as d 
    on a.virtuemart_product_id=d.virtuemart_product_id 
LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_product_categories as b 
    ON a.virtuemart_product_id = b.virtuemart_product_id 
LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_categories_el_gr AS c 
    ON b.virtuemart_category_id=c.virtuemart_category_id 
WHERE a.virtuemart_product_id = 508
```

The problem is that a product can have many categories , so this query returns me 3 rows, while i need to take always 1 row for output.

**virtuemart_product_categories:**
[image: Product_categories_table]

What i want is, when it check for the category here :

`LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_product_categories as b 
ON a.virtuemart_product_id = b.virtuemart_product_id` 
*put a LIMIT 1 statement*

I tried to use a nested select like this:

```
SELECT *,c.slug AS pslug,d.slug AS catslug
FROM uhhu_virtuemart_products as a 
WHERE uhhu_virtuemart_product_id =
    (SELECT virtuemart_product_id 
    from virtuemart_product_categories 
    where virtuemart_product_id=508 LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_categories_el_gr AS c 
ON a.virtuemart_category_id=c.virtuemart_category_id
LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_categories_el_gr as d 
on c.virtuemart_category_id=d.virtuemart_category_id
```

And Like this:

```
   SELECT *,c.slug AS pslug,d.slug AS catslug 
FROM uhhu_virtuemart_product_categories as a
LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_products_el_gr as d 
on a.virtuemart_product_id=d.virtuemart_product_id 
LEFT JOIN uhhu_virtuemart_categories_el_gr AS c 
ON a.virtuemart_category_id=c.virtuemart_category_id 
WHERE a.virtuemart_product_id =( 
    SELECT virtuemart_product_id 
    from uhhu_virtuemart_product_categories as f 
    where f.virtuemart_product_id=508 
    LIMIT 1)
```

I tried also use `SELECT distinct` but it didnt work too.I know only the basics of SQL and couldnt find something similar to help me solve this, so i would appreciate your help.

Hope i was clear enough.

Comment: DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows. RIGHT JOIN is too confusing for most people, so my tip is to do "main table LEFT JOIN additional-data".

Comment: You want me to change the RIGHT Joins to LEFT Joins ?

Comment: What you want to achieve with RIGHT JOIN? It joins new table's (`d`) all rows, even those where is no according key from table `a`. Is that you want here?

Comment: seems i missread then what Right join does :S im gonna edit it

Comment: You can also GROUP BY virtuemart_product_id

Comment: Cant believe i wasted so many hours without thinking of group by..It actually worked like a charm for my situation! Thanks!